# EF Core: How to Add and Delete Entity with many to many Relationship?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have here a problem with mxn Relationships:

```cs
public class User{
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class Permission{
    public int PermissionId{ get; set; }
    public int ProjectId{ get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<User?>? Users { get; set; }
}
```

Ef Core correctly created a PermissionUser Table (PermissiosnId,UserUserId) . I did not add anything in ModelBuilder.

My problem is that I don´t know **how to add new Permissions**, or how to add Permissions to certain Users and how to delete them.

My View is per Users, which shows all the Permissions, separated by the Project. However, I **only get back the clicked and not the unchecked Permissions**.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePermissions(IFormCollection form)
{
    var user = context......
    var changedPermissions = form.Where(y=>y.Key.Contains("Perm"));
    var currPerms = user.Permissions;

    user.Permissions.Clear(); //Delete everything, because we don´t know what was deleted
    
    foreach(var perm in changedPermissions)
    {
        var name = perm.SubString(".")[0];
        var project = perm.SubString(".")[1];

        user.Permissions.Add(new Permission()
        {
            Name=name,
            Project =project,
        });      
    }

    context.Update(user);
}
```

I have now the problem that when I am doing this everything in the permissionsUser table will be deleted and readded with a new id. However, everything that is already in the Permission table will stay, but not be used anymore. It will create a new row with the same Name and Project, but a **different ID**.

**->** How can I tell EF Core to use the existing Rows in Permission for the PermissionsUser table instead of adding new Permissions?

(I have already overwritten "Equals(object obj)" in Permission to only look at Name and Project, but it doesn´t change anything.)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why aren't you using a list of strings and a ModelBuilder for the configuration of that list?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the User entity does not have to have the navigation to Permissions. Not finding a relationship, you don't know what to remove.

You can include it in the following way:

```
var user = context.User.Include(r=>r.Permissions)....
OR
var user = context.User.Include(r=>r.PermissionsNavigation)....
OR
var user = context.User.Include("Permissions")....
```

Note: Depends on the name of your navigation property.

Adding the navigation property should now work.

```
user.Permissions.Clear();
```

Comment: Sorry, thought that it is clear that I have it. I am using: var user = await context.User .Include(y => y.Permissions).SingleOrDefaultAsync(y => y.UserId == userId); This loads all the Permissions the User is connected to.